# How do int-to-string casts work in Go?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

I only started Go today, so this may be obvious but I couldn't find anything on it.

What does `var x uint64 = 0x12345678; y := string(x)` give `y`?

I know `var x uint8 = 65; y := string(x)` would give `y` the byte 65, character `A`, and common sense would suggest (since types larger than `uint8` are allowed to be cast to strings) that they would simply be packed in to native byte order (i.e little endian) and assigned to the variable.

This does not seem to be the case:

```
hex.EncodeToString([]byte(y)) ==> "efbfbd"
```

First thought says this is an address with the last byte being left off because of some weird null terminator thingy, but if I allocate two `x` and `y` variables with two different values and print them out I get the same result.

```
var x, x2 uint64 = 0x10000000, 0x20000000
y, y2 := string(x), string(x2)
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString([]byte(y))) // "efbfbd"
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString([]byte(y2))) // "efbfbd"
```

Maddeningly I can't find the implementation for the string type anywhere although I probably haven't looked hard enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in the [Spec: Conversions: Conversions to and from a string type:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to `"\uFFFD"`.

So effectively when you convert a numeric value to `string`, it can only yield a `string` having one `rune` (character). And since Go stores `strings` as the UTF-8 encoded byte sequences in memory, that is what you will see if you convert your `string` to `[]byte`:

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.

When you try to conver the `0x12345678`, `0x10000000` and `0x20000000` values to `string`, since they are outside of the range of valid Unicode code points, as per spec they are converted to `"\uFFFD"` which in UTF-8 encoding is `[]byte{239, 191, 189}`; when encoded to hex string:

```
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString([]byte("\uFFFD"))) // Output: efbfbd
```

Or simply:

```
fmt.Printf("%x", "\uFFFD") // Output: efbfbd
```

Read the blog post [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) for more details about `string` internals.

And btw since Go 1.5 the Go runtime is implemented (mostly) in Go, so these conversions are now implemented in Go and can be found in the [`runtime`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) package: [`runtime/string.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/string.go), look for the `intstring()` function.