# Appending integer to a string by casting and using the concatenation operator

Tags: string, go, integer, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate an integer with an existing string by `casting` and the appending using `+`.  But it doesn't work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 4 
    b := "The value of a is "

    fmt.Println(b + string(a))
}
```

This prints a garbage character on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V9nAJ2jzMk) and nothing on the Unix terminal. What could be the reason for this? What is incorrect with this method?

Comment: It's not printing a "garbage character"; it's printing a character with the Unicode code point 4.

Comment: Minor technical point: Note that Go doesn't do casting, only type conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do int-to-string casts work in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808465/how-do-int-to-string-casts-work-in-go/34808496#34808496)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do int-to-string casts work in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808465/how-do-int-to-string-casts-work-in-go)

Comment: Also see related question: [Golang: format a string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int value to string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105935/how-to-convert-an-int-value-to-string-in-go)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Go language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

In order to achieve the desired result, you need to convert your int to a string using a method like [`strconv.Itoa`](https://godoc.org/strconv#Itoa):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    a := 4 
    b := "The value of a is "

    fmt.Println(b + strconv.Itoa(a))
}
```

Comment: Why is it like that?

Comment: That's how the language is defined.

Answer (score 7):

Use `fmt.Sprintf` or `Printf`; no casting required:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%s%d",s,i)
```